# SQL Server Integration Package fails with non-descript error. Works in VS2019 but not from commandline using DTEXEC

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2016

I'm having issues running a .dtsx package made in Visual Studio 2019.
In Visual Studio when using "Start without debugging" it runs perfectly with no errors, however when I try to launch the file from command line it's giving me a non-descript error and terminates the package.
It runs for some time and does execute a few of the tasks at the start of the package, however it does not get very far.

This is the "error" showing in the command prompt:
Message: <DTS:ProcessMemoryUsage xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts">DTS:PeakWorkingSetSize177860608</DTS:PeakWorkingSetSize></DTS:ProcessMemoryUsage>

[image: Error Message]

When I look at the error dump, this is what I see:

[image: SQL Dump File]

This is my execution command

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "C:\**PATH**\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\DataDropPrep\DataDropPrep\MSX DataDrop.dtsx" /conf "C:\**PATH**\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\DataDropPrep\Test.dtsConfig" /DECRYPT "****" /CONSOLELOG /DumpOnError /REPORTING EW
```

I don't understand why it works perfectly when run within Visual Studio 2019 but not in the commandline.
The package is set with target server 2016 (To match our SQL server).

I'm running the package from a local VM on my own PC, but the SQL server is deployed in Azure (cloudapp.azure.com).
I am NOT a DB admin, so I can't add the package to be run from the SQL Server itself unfortunately, wish that I could, would make my life a lot easier.
Alas I am stuck manually running this package every day from my own PC, and I'm trying to automate it with a .bat file, so I need this command working.

This is the package layout, it first truncates a staging table, then loads all items modified or created in the past 3 days, then deletes matching rows in the production table, then imports the new rows from staging. Repeat for all the different objects:

[image: Visual Studio Project View]

When using "Start without debugging" from Visual Studio 2019, it executes without issues:
[image: Start Without Debugging Success]

Comment: Without even knowing what the package does, very difficult to even begin to be able to answer this.

Comment: It's essentially an ETL package.
It truncates a staging table, then loads anything modified or created in the last 3 days to the staging table, then merges the staging table with the live table. It's from one SQL server to another SQL server

Comment: I have added additional info to the post, including a package overview, hope this helps

Comment: If you change your invocation to `"C:\Program Files *x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"` does it work from the command line?

Comment: The message about PeakWorkingSetSize is not an error message I've ever seen. It smells more like an informational level piece of information.  Given the multi-path nature of the constraints after the load roaster step and elsewhere, the error itself could be the first step of Notes path but the log there will be filled with Campaign/Users/Accounts so you'd need to scroll back up higher to find it. I would amend your invocation to include informational messages and then direct output to a file so you can review afterwards `/rep IEW "C:\temp\MSXDataDrop.txt"`

Comment: @billinkc Thanks, I tried to get logging working earlier but didn't get it working. I tried your suggestion there, but I just get this "Option "C:\temp\MSXDataDrop.txt" is not valid.". I figure I would need to use the /L function but this seems to require setup directly in VS as part of the connection manager or the config file? I'm not exactly an expert in this yet, I'm still learning

Comment: I butchered the command line for x86 Should have been `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe"`

Comment: Oh and I see comments appeared to have swallowed the redirect `/REP IEW > "C:\temp\MSXDataDrop.txt"` and in case it goes away, there's a greater than sign between REP and the path

Comment: A confusing, for me at least, point of SSIS is the wealth of means for recording "what happened". Often, people think "Oh, I want Logging" but that's a complicated beast and needs to be established as design-time (at least for the Package Deployment Model - which you're using). What most people want is available from Events and Reporting. That `/REP EIW` specifies report Error, Information and Warning _events_  The second change I suggested redirects the standard out/error streams into a text file that is created/overwritten per execution

Comment: @billinkc Now we're getting somewhere. After some searching through the log file (250k rows) I found this:
´Message: Accessing variable "{60CC2676-0FB6-49C8-92B6-0A05EBADD666}" failed with error code 0xC0010001.´
Given that this runs from Visual Studio without issues, I'm assuming this is something passed from VS to to DTEXEC which I dont have in my config file or in the execution line. This happened 6 times, both with "Campaigns" and "Accounts". Not sure what this means

Comment: Is the issue that I'm using a project parameter, instead of a package parameter? I'm gonna try to move my parameter to the package and see if this helps

Comment: 100% the issue. I was explicitly mentioning Package Deployment Model in my comment as that was the syntax you were using for invocation. Project deployment model will take the form of `dtexec /package MyPackage.dtsx /project Project\bin\Development\Project.ispac`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that I was using a project parameter, which works when running from Visual Studio, but not when executing the dtsx file directly.
After converting the parameters from project to package, it executes successfully!

Without the logging and the insights that provided I wouldn't have known where to start.

[Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lv635.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the same folder as the package, SSIS generated a file `SQLDUMPER_ERRORLOG.log`.  This pointed to a file in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Shared\ErrorDumps`.  This folder contains text files such as `SQLDmpr0085.mdmp`.  When I click on this, it launches Visual Studio and gives an error message "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access."

After hours of experimenting and doing web searches, I discovered that I was not passing the correct package name to `dtexec.exe`.  Once I corrected this, I was able to execute packages with no issues.